# Installing and printing HP laserjet P 1108

Tags: printing, hp, plugins

I installed UBUNTU 22.04 but my printer hp LaserJet p1108 shows printing stopped.Whenever I tried to install hp plugin it shows that hp plugin is not responding

Comment: Did you install the `hplip` package? What exactly do you mean by the plugin is not responding? Can you add more details/screenshots?

Comment: Can't find the hplip package for HP laserJet P1108

Comment: Can any one say which hplip package i want to install for my printer HP LaserJet P1108

Comment: `sudo apt install hplip-gui`